# How to do Left Associative Parenthesizing of a String in Java

Tags: java

Good day, I'm pretty new in Java and want to try and parenthesize a string in a Left-Associative manner like this, how do I go about in approaching this?

```
abcde
1st -> (ab)cde
2nd -> ((ab)c)de
3rd -> (((ab)c)d)e
```

is an implementation of a stack necessary here? or is there an easier approach to it?

Comment: I really am not sure what you're trying to accomplish.  Do you want to write a method that takes an `int` (1, 2, or 3 in your above example)?  Or do you want to return just the last one, or a list of `String`s, or what?  Why does the first set of parentheses have exactly 2 letters, instead of 1, 3, or some other number?  Is this an algebra expression where you're multiplying 5 variables?  Or what?  We really don't know what you're looking for.

Comment: You can do this easily via either a stack or recursion.

Comment: @ajb What I meant was given a String, the program will automatically add the parenthesis. So if I input abcde, it will return (((ab)c)d)e, the 1st,2nd,3rd was placed just to show how I'd do it on paper. Sorry for not explaining it thoroughly. Actually I'll just be using your answers to solve much more complex expressions in Untyped Lamda Calculus, such as  something like this λabc.abc ->  λa .(λb.(λc.((ab)c)))

Comment: You still haven't explained it thoroughly.  "Automatically add the parenthesis" doesn't tell me _where_.  All I have is your example.  To convert `abcde` to `(((ab)c)d)e`, you can subtract 2 from the string length, add that many `(` to the front, then add `)` after every other character.  If this doesn't work on other strings, you will need to explain it in a way that makes things clear for all the input strings you want to use.  One example isn't enough.  Three examples probably isn't enough.  Explanations and definitions are needed.

Answer (score -1):

- Start with the leftmost two characters. Add parenteses.
- Append the next character. Add parentheses.
- Append the next character. Add parentheses.
- And so on, until you reach the end of the string.

Comment: What I meant was given a String, the program will automatically add the parenthesis. So if I input abcde, it will return (((ab)c)d)e, the 1st,2nd,3rd was placed just to show how I'd do it on paper. Sorry for not explaining it thoroughly.